# Javascript for closing only mobile navigation - One page site

Tags: javascript

I created One-page site, and I have navigation with some efects for One page site. Also, I have mobile navigation, and now I want to create script for  closing mobile navigation when user click on some item. I found many answers for similar problem, but I cant finish script. This is my script, but not work:

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 600) {
    $('#button-toggle').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $('.navtg').toggleClass('open').show();
    });

    $('.menutg a').on('click', function() {
      $(".menutg").hide();
      $("#button-toggle").removeClass("active");
    });
  }
});
```

Thank you